# my Recyclerview only show last item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I am using `recyclerview` to display the values. I got response from retrofit but its `recyclerview` only show last one item.
Its working multiple array but its not working multiple object.

functions:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        attemptslist = testHistoryResponseList.get(position).getAttempts();

    Log.e("size", String.valueOf(attemptslist.size()));
  for(int i = 0 ; i< attemptslist.size(); i++){

       holder.binding.dashboardTestHistorySubjectNameTv.setText(attemptslist.get(i).getTestName());

        Log.e("name", String.valueOf(attemptslist.get(i).getTestName()));

        holder.binding.textView.setText(Integer.toString(attemptslist.get(i).getCurrentAttempt()));

        holder.binding.dashboardTestHistoryTestDate.setText(attemptslist.get(i).getTestDate());

    }
            holder.binding.textView.setText(Integer.toString(attemptslist.get(i).getCurrentAttempt()));

            holder.binding.dashboardTestHistoryTestDate.setText(attemptslist.get(i).getTestDate());

        }
}
```

my api is multiple objects. here i attached my api.Its working multiple array but its not working multiple object.

```
{
    "test_dtl": [
        {
            "test_id": 9,
            "attempts": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 13,
                    "test_id": 9,
                    "test_instance_id": 93,
                    "current_attempt": 2,
                    "End_Time": "27-Jun-18 01:20:am",
                    "org_id": 2,
                    "user_id": 9,
                    "test_name": "science test",
                    "test_desc": "science test",
                    "Test_Date": "27-Jun(16:49)",
                    "percent_score": "20.00"
                },
                {
                    "schedule_id": 16,
                    "test_id": 9,
                    "test_instance_id": 110,
                    "current_attempt": 2,
                    "End_Time": "28-Jun-18 03:22:am",
                    "org_id": 2,
                    "user_id": 9,
                    "test_name": "science test",
                    "test_desc": "science test",
                    "Test_Date": "28-Jun(13:31)",
                    "percent_score": "40.00"
                },
                {
                    "schedule_id": 18,
                    "test_id": 9,
                    "test_instance_id": 115,
                    "current_attempt": 1,
                    "End_Time": "28-Jun-18 01:49:am",
                    "org_id": 2,
                    "user_id": 9,
                    "test_name": "science test",
                    "test_desc": "science test",
                    "Test_Date": "28-Jun(17:07)",
                    "percent_score": "20.00"
                },
                {
                    "schedule_id": 18,
                    "test_id": 9,
                    "test_instance_id": 117,
                    "current_attempt": 2,
                    "End_Time": "28-Jun-18 02:31:am",
                    "org_id": 2,
                    "user_id": 9,
                    "test_name": "science test",
                    "test_desc": "science test",
                    "Test_Date": "28-Jun(17:20)",
                    "percent_score": "20.00"
                },
                {
                    "schedule_id": 18,
                    "test_id": 9,
                    "test_instance_id": 119,
                    "current_attempt": 3,
                    "End_Time": "28-Jun-18 02:52:am",
                    "org_id": 2,
                    "user_id": 9,
                    "test_name": "science test",
                    "test_desc": "science test",
                    "Test_Date": "28-Jun(18:11)",
                    "percent_score": "20.00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "test_id": 13,
            "attempts": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 51,
                    "test_id": 13,
                    "test_instance_id": 239,
                    "current_attempt": 1,
                    "End_Time": "14-Jul-18 01:26:am",
                    "org_id": 2,
                    "user_id": 9,
                    "test_name": "Half Yearly Test",
                    "test_desc": "Half Yearly Test",
                    "Test_Date": "14-Jul(10:38)",
                    "percent_score": "31.00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "timezone": "- HAST "
}
```

recyclerview .xml file `recyclerview` only show last one item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".test_history.TestHistoryFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_test_history_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Test History" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_dashboard_test_history"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dashboard_test_history_tv"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Activity code:

RetrofitService retrofitService = RetrofitServiceGenerator.getRetrofitOauthClient(getContext());

```
    Call<List<TestHistoryResponse>> testresponsecall = retrofitService.getdashBoardTestHistory(sessionManager.getOrgId());

    testresponsecall.enqueue(new Callback<List<TestHistoryResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<TestHistoryResponse>> call, Response<List<TestHistoryResponse>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                TestHistoryAdapter adapter = new TestHistoryAdapter(response.body(), getContext());

                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

                testHistoryBinding.rvDashboardTestHistory.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                testHistoryBinding.rvDashboardTestHistory.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<TestHistoryResponse>> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure " + t.getCause());
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure " + t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Group Scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

my recyclerview item xml file :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="12dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dashboard_test_history_subject_name_tv"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dashboard_test_history_test_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your recyclerview item XML?

Comment: I attach my recyclerview item xml

Comment: What do you want to show in Recyclerview? Your AttemplIst or testHistoryResponseList? Show your whole Adapter code along with what you need to show.

Comment: I want show attempt array in api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `onBindViewHolder` is showing only last entry of your Attempts  list.

I believe you wish to display Attempts list so  your `adapter` implementation is wrong you should use `attemptslist`

Your Adapter constructor should be somewhat like this

```
ArrayList<Attempt> attemptArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public void TestHistoryAdapter(ResponseObj obj, Context context){
    attemptArrayList=obj.getAttempts();
    this.context = context;}
```

Your `getItemCount` will return `attemptArrayList.size();`

Your `onBindViewHolder` should be something like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.binding.dashboardTestHistorySubjectNameTv.setText(attemptArrayList.get(position).getTestName());

    Log.e("name", String.valueOf(attemptArrayList.get(position).getTestName()));

    holder.binding.textView.setText(Integer.toString(attemptArrayList.get(position).getCurrentAttempt()));

    holder.binding.dashboardTestHistoryTestDate.setText(attemptArrayList.get(position).getTestDate());

    holder.binding.textView.setText(Integer.toString(attemptArrayList.get(position).getCurrentAttempt()));

    holder.binding.dashboardTestHistoryTestDate.setText(attemptArrayList.get(position).getTestDate());


}
```

Comment: where i pass test response to array list

Comment: in your adapter constructor `TestHistoryAdapter(response.body(), getContext());`

Comment: It will be easier to suggest changes if you can post your adapter implementaion

Comment: Hi.. Its shows only one subject .I got one subject and these attempts. but its not working in multiple subjects.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Sir.. I wish to show subjects and those attempts (ex. subject1 attempt1 , subject1 attempt2 ). This code is only show one subject and these attempts . but my api have multiple subject and multiple attempts.

Comment: please check it. and give me the solution

Comment: Please ask new SO question as you have a new requirement to your original question.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code before your for loop

```
List<String> att = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: @Gayathri share your layout.xml file and activity code with quetion

Comment: I attached my Recyclerview

Comment: @Gayathri just cross check that your row-item_layout of recyclerview is `wrap_content`

Comment: I change it as match_parent but results same(only show last one item).